# Ionic FB account KIT login sms

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

Trying to set login with FB account KIT on Ionic project but cant resolve error that I am getting. 
Here is Ionic page.html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                text-align: center;
                background: #EEE;
            }
            .mdl-button {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-offset">
            <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
            <h1 class="mdl-typography--title">Passwordless Authentication</h1>
            <h2 class="mdl-typography--subhead">Facebook Account Kit</h2>
            <p><strong>Login via:</strong></p>
            <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                  <button onclick="loginWithSMS();" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-typography--text-center">SMS</button>
                </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form id="my_form" name="my_form" action="/sendcode" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            <input type="text" id="code" name="code">
            <input type="text" id="csrf_nonce" name="csrf_nonce">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <script>
          // initialize Account Kit with CSRF protection
          AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
            console.log("{{csrf}}")
            AccountKit.init(
              {
                appId:myId,
                state:"{{csrf}}",
                version:"v1.1"
              }
            );
          };
          // login callback
          function loginCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
              document.getElementById("code").value = response.code;
              document.getElementById("csrf_nonce").value = response.state;
              document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
            }
            else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
              // handle authentication failure
            }
            else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
              // handle bad parameters
            }
          }
          function loginWithSMS(){
            AccountKit.login("PHONE",{}, loginCallback);
          }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting error when i press on button 'SMS' and error looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:
html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                text-align: center;
                background: #EEE;
            }
            .mdl-button {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-offset">
            <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
            <h1 class="mdl-typography--title">Passwordless Authentication</h1>
            <h2 class="mdl-typography--subhead">Facebook Account Kit</h2>
            <p><strong>Login via:</strong></p>
            <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">
              <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                  <button ng-click="loginWithSMS();" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-typography--text-center">SMS</button>
                </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form id="my_form" name="my_form" action="/sendcode" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            <input type="text" id="code" name="code">
            <input type="text" id="csrf_nonce" name="csrf_nonce">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

and I add js from html to controller.js:

```
AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
            console.log("{{csrf}}")
            AccountKit.init(
              {
                appId:appid,
                state:"{{csrf}}",
                version:"v1.1"
              }
            );
          };

    $scope.loginWithSMS = function() {

      function loginCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
              document.getElementById("code").value = response.code;
              document.getElementById("csrf_nonce").value = response.state;
              document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
            }
            else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
              // handle authentication failure
            }
            else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
              // handle bad parameters
            }
          }
       AccountKit.login("PHONE",{}, loginCallback);
    }
```